# How many degrees of freedom of $n$ spin 1/2 particles (discard spatial degrees of freedom)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, degrees-of-freedom

I think the state of the system can be expanded by basis $\{|000...0\rangle,|100...0\rangle,...|111...1\rangle\}$. So we can be completely certain of this state if we know the coefficient of these $2^{n}$ eigenstates.So there should be $2^{n}-1$ degrees of freedom. But I feel that it should be $2n$ simply because every particle provides 2 degrees of freedom. Maybe entanglement provided more possible degrees of freedom? I don't know if my understanding right.

Comment: You've just discovered one of the key differences between quantum mechanics and classical mechanics--in classical mechanics, you'd be correct!

Comment: The DoFs of the individual spins must be multiplied.

Comment: Got it, I think I'm confident with my understanding now!

Comment: My friend says n spin 1/2 particles system has $2^{n}$ complex-dimension so it has $2x2^{n}$ real-dimension. But I think density operator can completely specify a system so we just need the coefficients of the density operator, the system still have $2^{n}$ real-dimension. Which of us is correct?